# Cannot add new values to $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, associative-array

I've a very strange problem with a session variable.
This var is an associative array. I create this in a page (page A) with a lot of filterable items. I save filters in a session var

```
$_SESSION['filter'] = Array ( 'm' => 'acrylic', 'a' => 'P', 'c' => 1960 );
```

the user can go to a detail page (page B) but here I have

```
$_SESSION['filter'] = Array ( 'm' => 'acrylic', 'a' => 'P');
```

the strange is that when I go i the detail page I miss the last item in the associative array
so I can't go back with the right filter info.

I build the session var in this function, the options are passed in the URL example: http://www.web.com/artworks/a-P/c-1960/o-private+collection

the argument $args with this URL will be this array('a-P', 'c-1960', 'o-private+collection')

```
private function filter($args){
        // options
        $f = array('a','c','u','t','m','o');
    $a = array();

    foreach($args as $i){
        $t = explode('-', $i);
        if (in_array($t[0], $f)){
            $a[$t[0]] = urldecode($t[1]);
            $this->suffix .= '/'.$i;
        }
        else if(is_numeric($i))
            $a['pp'] = intval($i);
    }
    $_SESSION['filter'] = $a;

    return $a;
}
```

I call this in page A, In the page B I don't call this function the only interaction is

```
if (isset($_SESSION['filter'])){
print_r($_SESSION);
...
```

Someone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Jut to make sure there are no unexpected actions being taken on the session variable, try using `$_SESSION['filter2']` and see what happen

Comment: Do a `print_r($_SESSION)` before `return $a` and tell us what it prints out.

Comment: Array ( [m] => acrylic [a] => P [u] => 4 [t] => 2 [o] => private collection )

Comment: and this is what i get in the detail page

Comment: sorry Array ( [m] => acrilico [a] => P [u] => 4 [t] => 2 )

Comment: @Paolo: I 'm confused by that 'sorry'... does `$_SESSION` have what it should before the `return $a`?

Comment: @Jon I _think_ that was a sorry for doing it in a 3rd comment...

Comment: Basiclife is right, can you see the second print_r($_SESSION) has missed the last element

Comment: last test: I put print_r($_SESSION) before function call and after in the same page and if I reload I get the same result Array ( [m] => acrilico [a] => P [u] => 4 [t] => 2 ) and Array ( [m] => acrylic [a] => P [u] => 4 [t] => 2 [o] => private collection )

Comment: I don't know why but I solved this way: I added a slash at the end of the URL. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [`session_start`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) somewhere in your script before adding new values into `$_SESSION`, otherwise they will not persist. Do you do that?

Comment: The web app call session_start as first step and also use other session vars

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly but try with giving last varible value in quotes.

Comment: there are 6 filter options numeric and alphanumeric, I tried many combinations but not solve